# Counting, filtering, conditioning command in Excel

Tags: excel, database, dataframe, excel-formula, data-analysis

I am trying to solve this question. The question is:
A sport store target is to provide at least one employee per 10 customers and at least one administer officer per 10 customers. The store checks those figures running a report on the first Friday of the Month every 30 days.
I have added an example of the data. I am trying to identify the months during which the store failed to achieve those figures?
I would appreciate if anybody can help. please see the picture bellow.

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel do you have? Office 365, stand alone version?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you look into COUNTIFS, or SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: Hi @bugdrown, yes the it is Office 365, Version 2109.

Comment: Hi @P.b, yes, but I could not solve it yet.

Comment: Please post your formula attempts in your question.

Comment: =COUNTIFS($F$13:$F$412,"=customer",$A$13:$A$412,8)

Comment: =IF(H13/(G13/10)>=1,"True"

Answer (score 0):

`=LET(data,FILTER(A:B,(A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)>1)),a,INDEX(data,,1),b,INDEX(data,,2),u,UNIQUE(a),x,--(TRANSPOSE(a)=u),mmlt1,CEILING(MMULT(x,--(b="customer")),10)/10,mmlt2,MMULT(x,--(b="SECURITY")),mmlt3,MMULT(x,--(b="administer officer")),FILTER(u,(mmlt3<mmlt1)+(mmlt3<mmlt2),"all correct"))`

I took column A for `WEEK_ENDING` and B for `ROLE`
You can replace `FILTER(A:B,(A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)>1))` with your actual data (without headers).
I than took the unique dates and calculated

- the count of "customer` matching the date (mmlt1)
- the count of `SECURITY` matching the date (mmlt2)
- the count of `administer officer` matching the date (mmlt3)

I rounded up the customer count to the nearest 10 and then divided by 10.
Now either of the mmlt2 or mmlt3 values should be larger than the count of mmltq (round up & divided by 10) to meet the conditions.
Finally I filtered the unique dates to the conditions. The result spills the dates where either too little security was available per 10 customers, or too little administer officers.

Comment: It was a nice challenge.